# Bitnami apache + php-fpm stack can't disable buffer

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.4, buffer

I'm trying to get my service running that requires it output without a buffer. Is it possible to use php-fpm without a buffer with apache?

```
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/public.sock|fcgi://public-fpm" timeout=300>
    </Proxy>
</IfDefine>
<Directory "/var/www/public">
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All

    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://public-fpm/"
       </FilesMatch>
    </IfDefine>

</Directory>
```

I've made sure to disable `mod_deflate` and `output_buffering`. I'm using this script to test:

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
ob_implicit_flush(true);
out("Starting");
flush();

function out($string) {
    echo $string . PHP_EOL;
}

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 100) {
    out($i);
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

out("Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued digging until I found that mod_pagespeed was enabled! Disabling mod_pagespeed solved the issue.